# AWS Network ACL Rules for Docker

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-vpc

I want to setup AWS VPC Network ACL rules that allow docker pulls. Currently I'm blocked unless I allow all ICMP traffic on Incoming ports.

What are the specific ports I need to open in order to allow incoming/outgoing traffic for docker pulls? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have [configured custom ports](http://bind-docker-to-another-host-port-or-a-unix-socket), you should allow outbound port 2375 (plain text) or 2376 (SSL)

See [Service Name and Transport Protocol Port Number Registry](https://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.xhtml?search=docker)

For inbound, you need to specify the [ephemeral port range for your system](https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/10238)

Comment: I edited my question better, if I allow ALL TCP, I'm still blocked. If I allow ALL ICMP I able to do a docker pull. Any ideas?

Comment: Try to allow only the ICMP Echo Request incoming.

Comment: Just tried that, still getting a timeout error as it can't receive the response.

Comment: I also added Echo Reply but that also did not help, any other custom ICMP that might help ?

Comment: I am assuming there is ping attempt going on, so either Echo Reply or Echo Request

Comment: I tried both of those open on incoming, no positive result. Outgoing is wide open so it's not blocking there.

Comment: Try VPC flow logs. It will allow you to analyze the rejected traffic to/from the VPC http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/flow-logs.html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101729/discussion-between-rodrigo-m-and-rusty-shackleford).